# Question Regarding ISDATE Function and DATENAME Functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

We have had an issue this morning with a report failing due to the following error:

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

The issue is that in the database we had a value (in a VARCHAR field) of: '31.07/2021'

The report uses an ISDATE check to verify that the value is actually a date, and if so then pulls it apart using DATENAME functions (to get something thta ends up in a format similar to "DD-MMM-YYYY".

The issue is that even though ISDATE returns 1 for this value (indicating that it is interpreted by SQL Server as a date) the subsequent DATENAME functions throw the conversion error.

This is on SQL Server 2008 R2, but also tested on SQL 2012 & SQL 2016.

Repro code:

```
set dateformat dmy;

-- Date value from the database - note the mixture of '.' and '/' as separators
declare @the_date varchar(20) = '31.07/2021';

-- should return 1 - SQL interprets the above as a date
select isdate(@the_date);

-- All three of the DATENAME functions fail - why?
select DATENAME(dd,@the_date);

select DATENAME(MONTH,@the_date);

select DATENAME(YYYY,@the_date);
```

I would have expected that if a value returns 1 from ISDATE then any subsequent date-related functions should interpret the value correctly. Obviously I am missing something. :-)

If anyone can explain this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISDATE()` can be a tricky function, and you probably are better off using the explicit [`TRY_CONVERT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for testing if a value is properly formatted as a date.

My guess is that example value you specified is being treated as a date with time which is why `ISDATE()` returns true, similar to the [issue in this post](https://sqlservergeeks.com/dont-use-isdate-function-to-check-valid-date/).

Comment: J.D. - Many thanks, that's exactly what we needed.

Comment: @OwenWest Great, no problem!

Comment: @J.D. I just posted a slightly more verbose answer as well, which also gets to using `TRY_CONVERT` but also explains why OP's code throws an error. I thought the explanation would pique your interest!

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server data types & functions can be tricky.

Let's start with the `ISDATE()` function. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) describe the function fairly concisely:

> Returns 1 if the *expression* is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.

Even though the function is `ISDATE()`, it might be better called `ISDATEORTIMEORDATETIME()`. I guess the latter name just didn't make it past the Marketing department.

This means that the string you have ('31.07/2021') would translate to either a `date`, `time`, or `datetime` value. If it successfully is converted to any of those values, then `ISDATE()` will return true.

If we look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the `DATENAME()` function, we see that in the syntax, the second parameter is specifically a `date` value:

> DATENAME ( datepart , date )

You have these three queries, where `@the_date` is a `varchar` value:

```sql
SELECT DATENAME(dd,@the_date);
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,@the_date
SELECT DATENAME(YYYY,@the_date);
```

But because `DATENAME()` requires a date input, it will implicitly do this:

```sql
SELECT DATENAME(dd,CONVERT(date,@the_date));
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,CONVERT(date,@the_date));
SELECT DATENAME(YYYY,CONVERT(date,@the_date));
```

And that implicit conversion to `date` fails with the error you're seeing. This means that the value converts successfully to either a `time` or `datetime` successfully. And because it converts to one of them successfully, `ISDATE()` returns true.

We can use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `ISDATE()`. `TRY_CONVERT()` is more precise because it will only try to convert to the very specific conversion that is specified, rather than the loosey-goosey logic of `ISDATE()`.

By doing this, we see that the conversions to `date` and `time` fail, but the conversion to `datetime` succeeds.

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
DECLARE @the_date varchar(20) = '31.07/2021';

SELECT  TRY_CONVERT(date,@the_date),
        TRY_CONVERT(time,@the_date),
        TRY_CONVERT(datetime,@the_date);
```

If you are converting strings to dates, you **really** should do the conversion using explicit format codes, as [the only truly safe implicitly converted format](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly) is `YYYYMMDD`. All other date formats are subject to variations.

That said, if you are willing to roll the dice on date formats, or are getting varied & unpredictable date formats, you could roll the dice on the implicit conversions, and work around the problem you're seeing.

You can simply take your `varchar` date strings, and throw them into a `date` value, then pass that `date` value to `DATENAME`. You can leverage `TRY_CONVERT` to try to convert the string to both `date` and `datetime` and use one if it works. Something like this will work with all sorts of whacky formats, as long as it can be converted to EITHER `date` or `datetime`:

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
DECLARE @the_date_varchar varchar(20) = '31.07/2021';

DECLARE @the_date_date date;

SELECT @the_date_date = COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(date,@the_date_varchar),
                             TRY_CONVERT(datetime,@the_date_varchar)
                             );

SELECT @the_date_date

SELECT  DATENAME(dd,@the_date_date),
        DATENAME(MONTH,@the_date_date),
        DATENAME(YYYY,@the_date_date);
```

Comment: Interesting indeed, thanks! 

Comment: AMTwo, that's a great answer, really comprehensive. Thanks very much. Although, the process is currently only running on SQL 2008 R2, so no TRY_CONVERT(), unfortunately. We have opted for now to just log these as an error in the source data for correction by the users. :-)